# Prevent duplication of effort in Promise resolve/reject callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

So I have this simple scenario where the code in the two handlers are basically the same:

```
function runPromise(promise: Promise<any>) {

    ret.count++;

    return promise.then(function () {

      ret.count--;
      ret.count < 1 && ret.cb();

    }, function (err) {

      err && console.error(err.stack || err);

      ret.count--;
      ret.count < 1 && ret.cb();

    });
  }
```

one solution I could use is something like this:

```
  function runPromise(promise: Promise<any>) {
    ret.count++;

    let resolve = function(){
       ret.count--;
       ret.count < 1 && ret.cb();
    };

    return promise.then(resolve, function (err) {
      err && console.error(err.stack || err);
      resolve();
    });
  }
```

but I am wondering if there is a cleaner more elegant way of dealing with this situation? **I don't need to handle the error beyond logging it.**

Comment: What are you trying to do? As how I read it, you're trying to prevent a promise from firing twice, but a Promise only fires once, so that would be unnecessary...

Comment: I don't want to have to write the same exact code in two different functions.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: But why do you have a counter at all? You should either get rid of that entirely or replace it with `Promise.all()`, depending on what you're actually trying to do.  http://xyproblem.info

Comment: There is a lot of code outside of the context of the runPromise function, I have not included that code, but just demonstrating that it's possible to have nearly identical code in the onResolve/onReject handlers. The answer given by @SLaks is on point, please see that answer if you want to know what's up.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: But `Promise.all()` does exactly what you're apparently trying to do.  You should not need this at all.

Comment: Show me the money @SLaks, I do not see how Promise.all() helps here, but I would happy to see it in action (and others would as well). I will not remove your accepted answer so if you add to your answer, that would be great.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: That completely depends on how you're using your function.

Comment: the runPromise function is there in all its glory, I don't think the nature of runPromise can change that much, it's for a fairly special use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; you can use two callbacks:

```
promise
    .catch(err => err && console.error(err.stack || err))
    .then(...);
```

The `catch()` call will return a non-errored promise (it returns a promise of the result of its callback), so the second `then()` callback will always run.

However, your whole approach is flawed, because the caller will have no way of knowing whether the operation failed.

Comment: that should work, but I am not a big fan of catch handlers, because they can be invoked more than once, right?

Comment: @AlexanderMills: No; each handler is invoked at most once.  `.catch(fn)` is shorthand for `.then(null, fn)`.

Comment: I think catch can be invoked more than once, try a `setInterval` inside a promise and keep throwing errors :)

Comment: I don't need to handle the error beyond logging the error - I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: No; each promise is always resolved exactly once (or never). Throwing from `setInterval` won't do anything, because you wouldn't actually be throwing from inside any promise callback.